# unable to bind $scope.profile to a view from controller to view

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[theres what i've logged click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPM93.png) ok im now getting this objects with google data i want to dig in to username and id and be able to bind it. how do i do that?

```
d {$$conf: Object, $id: "google:107950469269631469408", $priority: null}
$$conf
:
Object
$id
:
"google:107950469269631469408"
$priority
:
null
-KK87pj5tW9EL8hL9To7
:
Object
id
:
"google:107950469269631469408"
name
:
"muzi ngobe"
__proto__
:
Object
```

How do i achieve this the fetching of object in objects?

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://tasksbylima.firebaseio.com/");
 $scope.profile = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(authData.uid));
 console.log($scope.profile);
```

theres my firebase Json tree

```
{
  "users" : {
    "google:107950469269631469408" : {
      "-KK87pj5tW9EL8hL9To7" : {
        "id" : "google:107950469269631469408",
        "name" : "muzi ngobe"
      },

    }
  }
}





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="list card">
            <div class="item item-divider">{{profile.name}}</div>
            <div class="item item-body">
                <form class="list">
                    <ion-checkbox>{{profile.name}}</ion-checkbox>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: "loggin profile [object Object]" this occurs cuz You use string concatenation in console.log, so the .toString method executed for $scope.profile. To see the $scope.profile You can use `debugger;` or `console.log($scope.profile);`

Comment: im getting a NaN after removing the concationation and still not binded on the view

Comment: remove the + symbol also

Comment: ok i've made an update to the post i can now see the Object but its inside other object now how do i go about fetching the data for username and id inside it. look at update up there

Comment: can You format this from copy-paste to normal format. I can see name field, but what is username field?

Comment: its name actually i made a mistake with the username

Comment: So can You add a screenshot of console.log or format it to json in your question

Comment: ive added and screenshot of my log data. check the link up there

Answer (score 0):

You can unwrap your answer object by accessing to the first property of object:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://tasksbylima.firebaseio.com/");
var response = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(authData.uid));
var users = response[Object.keys(response)[0]];
var google = users[Object.keys(users)[0]];
var key = google[Object.keys(google)[0]];
console.log(key);
```

Comment: do `console.log(key.name)` instead of `$scope.profile.name = key.name;`

Comment: thats undefined too

Comment: i cant view this link Access denied

Comment: I'm sorry.. something was happend with screenshot. Here is a new one: http://i.prntscr.com/a6eb4348d9db4c1cb4779929ff4f1d25.png

Comment: i still cant access your screenshot

Comment: i modified the answer. Also you can use debugger to solve the undefined problem,